# Bluetooth low energy and wifi 2.4 Ghz interference on osx

Tags: macos, bluetooth, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently working on 2 applications (one on iOS and the other on Mac) that are communicating using Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth 4.0).
I develop these applications using CoreBluetooth on iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite.

I'm facing the following issue :

- On my Mac, if the Wifi is turned OFF or if it is connected to a 5 Ghz wifi network, I have a stable Bluetooth connection between the iPhone and the Mac. No problem.
- If my Mac is connected to a 2.4 Ghz Wifi network and if I have at least one Bluetooth device connected like a keyboard, trackpad, mouse... (using Classic Bluetooth), I have a stable Bluetooth connection between the iPhone and the Mac. No problem.
- If my Mac is connected to a 2.4 Ghz Wifi network, the Bluetooth connection becomes unstable : the connection is stopped almost every 10 seconds and in Xcode I get an error message telling that the connection had an unexpected timeout.

I spent days on the Internet to try to figure out what I can do.
The best answer I found was this answer : [CoreBluetooth and Wifi interference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380159/corebluetooth-and-wifi-interference)

But it means that I have to tell to my app's users to run this script and reboot their computer which is not for me a viable solution for production.

I also heard something about dealing with classical bluetooth peripherals (maybe to simulate one) or Wifi interfaces, but I found no solutions involving these kinds of manipulations.

Does anyone have an idea about something that I can do ? A workaround about the OSX Bluetooth management, the Wifi interfaces ?

I really need help about this issue.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.